# Display image in google sheet sidebar after dropdown selection

Tags: html, image, google-apps-script, sidebar

I am working on some small project using google sheet sidebar. My sidebar already has a dropdown which options are created based on the values of the specified cells in the spreadsheet. I am wondering whether it is even technically possibile to display image in sidebar after selection of the dropdown option. I would like to display image as a preview in sidebar just after I choose option from the dropdown but before I click "Add image to the spreasheet" button. So for example if I select "Banana" in the dropdown, the image of the banana will be displayed in the sidebar, just below  dropdown so that before I send it to the spreadsheet by clicking the button I can see what image I will be sending. I know there is an option to display images in selection options of the dropdown, next to the text, but this is not what I am looking for. I am not a programmer so please let me know if I can explain anything better.

I was already trying with some HTML codes found in web but nothing really works. I am not sure whether I should use some conditional statement in HTML code.

This is how the code looks right now.

GS:

```
function loadform() {
  var html = HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('ShowThefruit');

  html.dynamicdropdown = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:A5").getValues();


  html = html.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Show image of the fruit')
      .setWidth(8000);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

HTML

```
<body bgcolor="#046ED2">
  <font face="arial" color="white">
    <b>Choose an object.</b><br><br>

    <!-- Create input fields to accept values from the user -->
    Object:<br>
    <select id="Object">
    <? for (let i in dynamicdropdown) { ?>
      <option value="<?=dynamicdropdown[i]?>"><?=dynamicdropdown[i]?></option>
    <? } ?>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    PREVIEW OF THE IMAGE HERE
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button class="bnt btn-primary" id="mainButton" >Add image to the spreasheet</button>
```

Image will come from URL, so basically I would like to add below code to HTML but with condition of "Banana" value being selected from the dynamic dropdown.

```
<img src="URL OF BANANA PICTURE" width="50" height="60";>
```

Will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes it is definitely possible to display an image in a dialog, webapp or sidebar.  All of these are browser based environments and image display is a key feature of their capabilities.  Try doing some research on html image tag.

Comment: The basic process would probably be something like make selection.  Using on change event pass selection to server to get the url of the image and return it to your success handler and attach it to the images src property.

Answer (score 0):

Try

### code gs

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem('Open ...', 'loadform')
    .addToUi();
}

function loadform(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var html = HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile("index")
    .evaluate();
  html.setTitle("Show image of the ...");
  ui.showSidebar(html);
} 

function dynamicdropdown() {
  return  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:B5").getValues()
}
```

### code html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body bgcolor="#046ED2">
    <script>
      <? 
        var data = dynamicdropdown();
      ?>
    </script>
  <? var data = dynamicdropdown(); ?>
  <form>
      <select name="img" onchange="choose(this);" font face="arial" color="white">
        <option value="" disabled selected >Selectionner ...</option>
        <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
          <option value="<?= data[i][1] ?>" ><?= data[i][0] ?></option>
        <? } ?>
      </select>
  </form>
  <br/>
  <div id="myImg"></div>
  <script>
    function choose(item) {
      document.getElementById("myImg").innerHTML='<img src="'+item.value+'" style="width:290px"  >'
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]